# In cartesian product, is the order of factors important?

Tags: functions, relations

For example- $\{1,3\} \times \{1,2\}$. Here $4$ elements will be formed. So if i write $\{1,2\}$ before $\{1,3\}$, is there any difference?

Comment: $\{1,1\}$ denotes a set, right? That set only has one element: $\{1,1\} = \{1\}$.

Comment: sorry Hurkyl it was 1,3

Comment: What you are asking is about a set of four ordered pairs.  Sets are sets and order does not matter.  {(1,4),(3,2), (3,1), (1,1)} may be listed in any order.  It doesn't matter if it's a set of numbers, pairs, or elephants or a mixture of all. Order doesn'doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the elements of a Cartesian product are *ordered* tuples.

The Cartesian product is not commutative.   The order of its operation is significant.

$$\rm \forall A\neq\emptyset~,\forall B\neq\emptyset\qquad A\neq B~\to~ A\times B\neq B\times A$$

As per your example:

$\{1,3\}\times\{1,2\} = \{(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)\}$

$\{1,2\}\times\{1,3\} = \{(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3)\}$

Since the order *in the* tuples is significant, these are not the same sets.

---

If, however, you meant the order *of the* tuples within the product; the product is a set so *that* is not important.

$\{(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)\}=\{(1,1),(3,1),(1,2),(3,2)\}$ et cetera.

Comment: I am asking that in cartesian product 1st you have done, can i write (1,2) before (1,1). I am not changing number inside (  ) just changing position of element.

Comment: thnx that i was asking

Comment: Okay, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In Cartesian product of $\{1,3\} \times \{1,2\}$ order matters. So you can't write it as $\{1,2\} \times \{1,3\}$. But in the resultant set you can place elements at any position.